# Exception while running sonar-runner on a Java Project

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed `sonar-runner-1.0` and `sonar-3.1.1` on `MAC OS X 10.8.2`.
I configured sonar-runner for my stand alone project and tried running sonar-runner file for analysis of the code. But the script file returned an error which is as follows :

```
Error in socksNonProxyHosts system property:  sun.misc.REException: local is a duplicate
Sonar version: 3.5.1
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException:
org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file:
localhost:9000/batch
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:164)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.createClassLoader(Bootstrapper.java:87)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.createClassLoader(Main.java:151)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:48)
Caused by: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: localhost:9000/batch/
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:113)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:159)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /net/10.132.20.192/Users/498546/Desktop/sonar-runner-1.0/bin/./.sonar/batch
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:107)
... 5 more
```

I have even set the `SONAR_RUNNER_HOME` path for Java and created a`sonar_project.properties` file for my project and placed it in bin folder of sonar_runner.

Can anyone please suggest as what can be the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing things up.
Could you please download the latest versions: Sonar 3.5.1 and Sonar Runner 2.2?
Could you please follow the documentation:

1. Install [Sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar).
2. Install the [Sonar Runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner).
3. Read how to run an [analysis](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Runner) with the Sonar Runner.
4. Analyze a simple Java project [sample](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem). ('Run a Sonar Analysis' section).

If you encounter any issues, please come back with detailed information.

Thank you

David RACODON | SonarSource

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned by you with latest sonar versions. But now while running sonar-runner I am getting the error as :Error during Sonar runner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Status returned by url : 'http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/index' is invalid : 500